# Problem with Encode ISO-8859-1 when importing XML

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I'm having a small problem importing some XML due to Encode ISO-8859-1.
The process is currently divided into two phases, the part that validates the XML and displays a list of items not registered in the system and a list of products that already exist in the system, and the part that actually imports the items and makes associations within them. of the system.

In the first part, when there is an item that does not have an association in the system, it forces the client to associate the XML product with a product in the system before proceeding.

As the product is in XML:
**"GPM 25 / VALVULA GPMBRASIL PN 16 COMERCIAL 45º 2.1/2 11 BSP X 5 FPP LATAO C/ VOLANTE Ø 90 MM VERMELHO"**

How the product looks after being inserted into the system:
"**GPM 25 / VALVULA GPMBRASIL PN 16 COMERCIAL 45Âº 2.1/2 11 BSP X 5 FPP LATAO C/ VOLANTE Ã? 90 MM VERMELHO**"

I'm capturing the value through my controller like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = null;
using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
{
     xdoc = XDocument.Load(oReader);
}

using (var xmlReader = xdoc.CreateReader())
{
     importacao.XmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

Method I use to create the product list:

```
var produtosDoXML = nodeProdutos.Cast\<XmlNode\>().Select(x =\> new
{
Codigo = x\["prod"\]\["cProd"\].InnerText,
Descricao = x\["prod"\]\["xProd"\].InnerText,
NCM = x\["prod"\]\["NCM"\]?.InnerText,
CEST = x\["prod"\]\["CEST"\]?.InnerText,
EANTributavel = x\["prod"\]\["cEANTrib"\]?.InnerText,
EAN = x\["prod"\]\["cEAN"\]?.InnerText,
UnidadeComercial = x\["prod"\]\["uCom"\]?.InnerText,
Quantidade = Convert.ToDecimal(x\["prod"\]\["qCom"\].InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
Desconto = Convert.ToDecimal(x\["prod"\]\["vDesc"\]?.InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
ValorUnitario = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(x\["prod"\]\["vUnCom"\]?.InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 4),
OrdemDeExibicao = int.Parse(x.Attributes\["nItem"\].Value)
});

foreach (var produtoDoXML in produtosDoXML)
{
var produtos = produtosServicosDosFornecedores.Where(x =\> x.CodigoEquivalente == produtoDoXML.Codigo && x.DescricaoEquivalente == produtoDoXML.Descricao);

    if (produtos.Count() > 1)
    {
        throw new CompraException(CompraException.TypeException.ProdutoEquivalenteDeTerceiroDuplicado, "", produtoDoXML.Codigo);
    }
    else if (produtos.Count() == 0)
    {
        var produtosAssociadosAoCodigo = produtosServicosDosFornecedores.Where(x => x.CodigoEquivalente == produtoDoXML.Codigo)
                                                                        .GroupBy(x => x.ProdutoServicoId);
        if (produtosAssociadosAoCodigo.Count() == 1)
        {
            retornoDaImportacao.AdicionarProdutoNaoAssociadoComCodigoExistente(new RetornoImportacaoXMLDeNFeDeCompraDTO.ProdutoNaoAssociadoComCodigoExistente
            {
                IdDoProdutoAssociado = produtosAssociadosAoCodigo.Single().First().ProdutoServico.Id,
                CodigoDoProdutoAssociado = produtosAssociadosAoCodigo.Single().First().ProdutoServico.Codigo,
                DescricaoDoProdutoAssociado = produtosAssociadosAoCodigo.Single().First().ProdutoServico.Descricao,
                NomeDoFornecedor = fornecedor.NomeFantasia,
                IdDoFornecedor = fornecedor.Id,
                Codigo = produtoDoXML.Codigo,
                Descricao = produtoDoXML.Descricao,
                EAN = produtoDoXML.EAN,
                EANTributavel = produtoDoXML.EANTributavel,
                CEST = produtoDoXML.CEST,
                NCM = produtoDoXML.NCM,
                UnidadeComercial = produtoDoXML.UnidadeComercial,
                Valor = produtoDoXML.ValorUnitario,
            });
        }
        else
        {
            retornoDaImportacao.AdicionarErroDeProdutoServico(new RetornoImportacaoXMLDeNFeDeCompraDTO.ErroDeProdutoServico
            {
                Mensagem = string.Format(Language.Exception_ProdutoXNaoEncontrado, $"[{produtoDoXML.Codigo} - {produtoDoXML.Descricao}]"),
                NomeDoFornecedor = fornecedor.NomeFantasia,
                IdDoFornecedor = fornecedor.Id,
                Codigo = produtoDoXML.Codigo,
                Descricao = produtoDoXML.Descricao,
                EAN = produtoDoXML.EAN,
                EANTributavel = produtoDoXML.EANTributavel,
                CEST = produtoDoXML.CEST,
                NCM = produtoDoXML.NCM,
                UnidadeComercial = produtoDoXML.UnidadeComercial,
                Valor = produtoDoXML.ValorUnitario
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        retornoDaImportacao.AdicionarProdutoAssociado(new RetornoImportacaoXMLDeNFeDeCompraDTO.ProdutoAssociado
        {
            IdDoProduto = produtos.First().Id,
            CodigoDoProdutoAssociado = produtos.First().ProdutoServico.Codigo,
            DescricaoDoProdutoAssociado = produtos.First().ProdutoServico.Descricao,
            NomeDoFornecedor = fornecedor.NomeFantasia,
            IdDoFornecedor = fornecedor.Id,
            Codigo = produtoDoXML.Codigo,
            Descricao = produtoDoXML.Descricao,
            EAN = produtoDoXML.EAN,
            EANTributavel = produtoDoXML.EANTributavel,
            CEST = produtoDoXML.CEST,
            NCM = produtoDoXML.NCM,
            UnidadeComercial = produtoDoXML.UnidadeComercial,
            Valor = produtoDoXML.ValorUnitario,
        });
    }
}
```

So as the product looks different when it is inserted, when I need to compare it again in the future, it will not find a product that is already registered in the system.

Comment: I don't think iso-8859-1 contains characters for degree or diameter. Isn't it utf8?

Comment: I believe that the XML file is UTF-8, but when passing through StreamReader the encode changes to ISO-8859-1, unfortunately I cannot simply change streamreader to UTF-8 as well, as there are already many other old records in the system

Comment: *Remove* `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`. StreamReader doesn't change the encoding, it [uses UTF8 by default](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L137). It's *the question's code* that mangles the text. `Âº` is how the two bytes that represent `º` appear if you try to read them as Latin1

Comment: Why was the `entity-framework` tag used? There's no database code in the question. Is the data saved in a database field? What database, using what type and encoding or collation? Does the text appear mangled *after* you try to read it? If the XML text is stored as UTF8 in the database you need to use UTF8 to read it back, not Latin1

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the fact that the system was trying to read a UTF-8 file as an ISO-8859-1 file, which caused broken characters. To solve the problem, I converted the Encoding of the file and it started working.

```
    private string lerEConverterArquivoXML(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        Encoding srcEncoding;
        var destEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        string fileContent;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream, true))
        {
            fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            srcEncoding = reader.CurrentEncoding;
        }

        byte[] srcBytes = srcEncoding.GetBytes(fileContent);
        byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(srcEncoding, destEncoding, srcBytes);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(isoBytes))
        {
            using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(ms, destEncoding))
            {
                return oReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that your data is stored in your system (database) with UTF-8 encoding, you can change the XDocument (xdoc) encoding to UTF-8 after it has been read with StreamReader:

```
XDocument xdoc = null;
using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
{
     xdoc = XDocument.Load(oReader);
}
xdoc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");

using (var xmlReader = xdoc.CreateReader())
{
     importacao.XmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

so you are sure that your xml file is already UTF-8 encoded when it is saved.

Comment: This changes nothing. The text is already mangled by using Latin1 to read a UTF8 file. Changing the XML prologue won't change the already mangled text

Comment: No, when reading from XML, the text is right, like it appears in the message. It is when it is saved that become mangled, beacuse when it read from the stream is "8859-1", and the column format is UTF-8.

Comment: Even if the original file is Latin1, changing the XML prologue won't have any effect on the data or how they're exported to another file or a database. It's the StreamWriter's encoding that controls how the data is written to a file. C# strings are UTF16.

Comment: Besides, the question shows that only non-ANSI characters were treated as 2 bytes. That's what happens when UTF8 is read using a single-byte encoding

Comment: The phrase "As the product is in XML:" is a text read from the stream with "ISO-8859-1" encoding, and converted (in memory and displaying) in a string (obviously string internal format is UTF-16). Now he should save it converting first in UTF-8 (variable bytes encoding). Right?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution:

```
XDocument xdoc = null;
using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
{
     byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(oReader.ReadToEnd());                
     string fileString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
     xdoc = XDocument.Parse(fileString);
}

using (var xmlReader = xdoc.CreateReader())
{
     importacao.XmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

Now, it doesn't matter if the input stream is UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1. It will be correctly encoded to UTF-8 format.

Comment: No, you are reading a UTF-8-encoded file as ISO-8859-1, converting it back to (the original UTF-8) bytes using ISO-8859-1, then decoding it again (correctly) as UTF-8.  Just read it as UTF-8 to begin with.  This won't read an actually ISO-8859-1-encoded file correctly, because decoding it as UTF-8 will fail.